# How to send an Ad Hoc to a device I do not own

Tags: ios, adhoc, software-distribution, ad-hoc-distribution

Creating an app for a customer and am not certain how to distribute the app Ad Hoc.

1. I added an Ad Hoc distribution provisioning profile on the apple developer portal.
2. I then exported an archive using that distribution provisioning profile through xcode.
3. Uploaded that archive to Diawi.
4. User receives install error.

Is this due to the fact that I do not have his particular device in my provisioning profile device options to select from?

How would I go about doing this?

I.E. in the listening when I add a new distribution profile for Ad Hoc I get to the page that says "Select the devices you wish to include in this provisioning profile. To install an app signed with this profile on a device, the device must be included."

And I do not own their device so I cannot add it to my list.

Comment: You need to add the user's device to the provisioning profile.

Comment: If I do not own their device how can I do that?

Comment: They need to send you their device's UDID or use a service like TestFlight to make it easy.

Comment: Ask the owner the device UDID, he can found it using iTunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get their Unique Device Identifier (UDID) and add it to your list of devices. You do not have to "own" the device but do need their UDID.

Here is a site showing how to get the UDID from iTunes:
http://whatsmyudid.com

You can also get it from Xcode:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood/organizerudid